# VB6 general search form

Tags: visual-basic-6

I'm working on an old vb6/access2003 app which is used to handle orders, bills of materials and that sort of things. I'm thinking about creating a form that I call every time the users needs to search for something. This should work like these:

- Click on the field to complete, let's say name of a buyer
- Open new form, search for the client and click on it
- Return the name of the buyer to the previous form (probably the header of the order)

So, I would need to pass to the new form something that identify the type of search I have to do (so what access table to open) and return some values.

Is my idea correct or there something better? I would like to use only one form for all the searches, now the app works with a lot of msflexgrid for every form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a full object oriented language, one could apply the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here. The idea is to have a base class `SearchStrategy` and for each kind of search a derived child class. The objects of this class should provide all meta data ("which table / columns to search for", "which parameters to enter from the user for this search"), or specific search methods. Then, one would pass the specific `SearchStrategy` object into the generic search form, and the form uses the strategy to do the search.

Though VB6 is not a full OO language like VB.NET, it provides indeed enough polymorphism capabilities to implement that pattern. See [here](http://www.jasinskionline.com/TechnicalWiki/Polymorphism-in-VB6.ashx) or [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/203752-polymorphism-inheritance-patterns-vb), for example.